# How do I remove brackets and bracketed contents?

Tags: javascript, regex

I tried `.replace(/ *\[[^)]*\] */g, "");` and it works for instances where there's only a pair of brackets

```
"[Dialog4]Hello, this is Mike"
```

but doesn't work for

```
"[Dialog4]Hello, this is Mike[Dialog5]"
```

because it just removes entire thing

The result should be

```
"Hello, this is Mike"
```

Comment: Change `)` to `\]` so that you match non `]` characters instead of non `)` characters.

Comment: `"[Dialog4]Hello, this is Mike[Dialog5]".replace(/\[[^\]]+\]/g,'')`

Comment: As @Paulpro turned out the issue is due to a typo ")" instead of "\". Can be closed (even if there are simpler expressions provided for the problem as described).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
\[[^\]]*\]
```

[image]

```js
let str = "[Dialog4]Hello, this is Mike[Dialog5]" 

let replaced = str.replace(/\[[^\]]*\]/g,"")

console.log(replaced)
```

Answer (score 3):

use not greedy mode in regex:

```
\[.*?\]
```

here is a tester: https://regex101.com/r/NyireC/1

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is almost there.

You don't need the space+`*` at the start and end, because you only want to replace the square brackets and their contents, not anything before/after it.

In the negated character class, you are negating `)`, where you *should* be negating `]` instead. This is possibly a typo.

With these modifications, the regex becomes:

```
\[[^\]]*\]
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aF7t8z/1)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a bit sloppy, but you could use the regex `/\[(?<=\[)[^\]]*(?=\])]/g`.
This makes use of both a positive lookbehind and positive lookahead, on the `[` and `]` characters respectively.

```js
const string = "[Dialog4]Hello, this is Mike[Dialog5]";
const regex = /\[(?<=\[)[^\]]*(?=\])]/g;
const output = string.replace(regex, "");

console.log(output);
```